# HTTP GET with my API

Tags: api, asp-classic

I have a current web site that captures data send via querystring
I would like to repost this data to a different API using HTTP GET and capture the response from that site. Response.Redirect works but can not read the results of that post.

Comment: Use the `Server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")` to send the request.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code should get you started. It requests the page from a url with querystring values passed, and stores the response in a variable then response.write's the contents.

```
Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objXML.Open "GET", "http://www.test.com/test.asp?var1=val1", false 
objXML.Send ""
strResponse = objXML.ResponseText
Response.Write strResponse
```

Comment: is this correct strResponse objXML.ResponseText or should it be strResponse = objXML.ResponseText

Comment: You are right. I left off the equals sign. I have edited the answer.